# Issue with making my accordion close and open

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

When I click the Icon/ Button, it should open and display the information. However, nothing happens when I click it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdLZL.png) This is how it looks normally, when you click on it, it should expand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAIxQ.png) This is how it should look when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion button");

            function toggleAccordion() {
                const itemToggle = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded');
  
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    items[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                }

                if (itemToggle == 'false') {
                    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                }
            }

            items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
  
        </script>

        <title>FAQ</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="ice_cream.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="ul-nav">
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
/* FAQ Page  */

.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4rem;
    width: 48rem;
}

.accordion {
  .accordion-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    button[aria-expanded='true'] {
      border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    }
  }
  .accordion-item button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    color: rgb(66, 61, 61);
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    &:hover, &:focus {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: blue;
      &::after {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    }
    .accordion-title {
      padding: 1em 1.5em 1em 0;
    }
    .icon {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 18px;
      right: 0;
      width: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 22px;
      &::before {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 9px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 10px;
        height: 2px;
        background: currentColor;
      }
      &::after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 5px;
        left: 10.5px;
        width: 2px;
        height: 10px;
        background: currentColor;
      }
    }
  }
  .accordion-item button[aria-expanded='true'] {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    .icon {
      &::after {
        width: 0;
      }
    }
    + .accordion-content {
      opacity: 1;
      max-height: 9em;
      transition: all 200ms linear;
      will-change: opacity, max-height;
    }
  }
  .accordion-content {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear, max-height 200ms linear;
    will-change: opacity, max-height;
    p {
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 2em 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I can manually change the aria-expanded to true and it will change. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it could be as simple as reordering your JavaScript after your HTML, or, adding some kind of DOM listener to fire the JavaScript only after the DOM has prepared the elements. I don't think they exist to attach the listener to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>FAQ</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="ice_cream.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul id="ul-nav">
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li class="li-nav"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <button id="accordion-button-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="accordion-title">When are you guys open?</span><span class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <div class="accordion-content">
                        <p>We are open every day of the week from 10am to 8pm.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            const items = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion button");

            function toggleAccordion() {
                const itemToggle = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded');
  
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    items[i].setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                }

                if (itemToggle == 'false') {
                    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                }
            }

            items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordion));
  
        </script>
<!-- Reposition to here, at the end --> 
    </body>
</html>
```